# Documentation concerning platform-specific macros in Linux/POSIX

Tags: c++, c, linux, macros, posix

When compiling a C/C++ program under Windows using Visual Studio (or a compiler that tries to be compatible) there is a predefined macro _WIN32 (Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) that you can use for platform-specific #ifdef-s.

What I am looking for is an analogon under Linux: a macro which tells me that I am compiling for Linux/an OS that claims to be (more or less) POSIX-compatible.

So I looked into gcc documentation and found this: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System_002dspecific-Predefined-Macros.html

Applied to my program, the following macros (gcc 4.4.5 - Ubuntu 10.10) looked promising (I hope that I didn't drop an important macro):

```
#define __USE_BSD 1
#define __unix__ 1
#define __linux 1
#define __unix 1
#define __linux__ 1
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1
#define __STDC_HOSTED__ 1
#define __STDC_IEC_559__ 1
#define __gnu_linux__ 1
#define __USE_SVID 1
#define __USE_XOPEN2K 1
#define __USE_POSIX199506 1
#define _G_USING_THUNKS 1
#define __USE_XOPEN2K8 1
#define _BSD_SOURCE 1
#define unix 1
#define linux 1
#define __USE_POSIX 1
#define __USE_POSIX199309 1
#define __SSP__ 1
#define _SVID_SOURCE 1
#define _G_HAVE_SYS_CDEFS 1
#define __USE_POSIX_IMPLICITLY 1
```

Where do I find a detailed documentation of them - as to the mentioned Windows-specific macros above?

Additionally I'd be interested in macros normally defined for other POSIX-compliant operating systems as *BSD etc.

Comment: Some of the macros you listed are feature test macros (see http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html), which don't work the way you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I once collected the identifying macros for use by pkgsrc, a cross-platform package system: http://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/fixes.html#fixes.build.cpp

I didn't find any authoritative source back then.

Answer (score 7):

The [glibc manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) lists several of these macros, including `_POSIX_SOURCE`. However, they work differently from what you might expect: the programmer defines these macros (in a build script, probably) and the C library headers check it to enable or disable certain functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, there are two games in town: Windows, and POSIX.  You're very likely to be able to get what you want with `#ifndef _WIN32`, therefore.  Distinctions among the surviving Unix variants are best done with autoconf-style feature tests, e.g. `#ifdef HAVE_SYS_WHATEVER_H`; but don't bother with any of those till you know you need one.  Many of the stock tests in the autoconf manual are unnecessary nowadays.

(VMS and whatever IBM is calling its non-Unixy mainframe OS these days *might* still count as more games in town, but I wouldn't bother trying to be portable to either of those until someone asked for it.)